# How can I allow the user to set a custom global value in the silverstripe CMS?

Tags: silverstripe

I would like to be able to set custom values in the CMS, such as with the site name and tagline. I can't currently find any way of doing this other than on individual pages.

Comment: Here is a great lesson on extensions. At the bottom of the lesson there is an example of how to extend the site config, which shows how to add global variables: 
http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/data-extensions-and-siteconfig

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find a specific answer to my particular issue, and I'd not got this far in the lessons yet so hadn't seen this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by extending `SiteConfig`. Your Extension might look like this:

```
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array(
        'CustomContent' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',
            TextField::create('CustomContent', 'Custom content')
        );
    }
}
```

Then you need to apply the extension to `SiteConfig`. Add the following to `mysite/_config/config.yml`

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig
```

And that's it. Run `dev/build` and your new field should be editable in the CMS as well as accessible in the Template using: `$SiteConfig.CustomContent`